# Replace am/pm with a.m/p.m in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have date with time like this: '00:30am';

Using javascript slice functions I split the string and perform the required operation.

```
strStartTimeZone.slice(0, 5); // outputs 00:30
strStartTimeZone.slice(5); // outputs am/pm
```

Want a.m or p.m instead of am or pm.

This value is binded from timepicker plugin. Are there any way to customize it? Any suggestions for a.m or p.m ?

Comment: `.replace(/(.)m/g, '$1.m')`

Comment: Why would you want "a.m", as compared to "a.m."? Both "am" and "a.m." are pretty standard, but I've never before seen "a.m". *"This value is binded from timepicker plugin. Are there any way to customize it?"* - There may be ways to customise it, but there are multiple time-picker plugins - which one, specifically, are you using? (Also, both of your `.slice()` examples are wrong: the arguments `(0,5)` and `(5)` would not produce either of the outputs you claim.)

Comment: Simply use replace like ---- '03/23/2017 00:30am'.replace('am','a.m')

Comment: @nnnnnn: corrected the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` and `join` of JavaScript, look like this.

```
var amOrPm = 'am'; // string output for am or pm
var data = amOrPm.split('').join('.'); // split it and join it.
console.log(data) // result 'a.m'
```